# Can't call handler in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

I want to create a background thread (execute even if my activity dies) that update my data location et send it to my server with an http resquest. But it occurs an exception:

```
02-01 07:50:18.172: ERROR/Exception1(277): Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

My code:

```
public class Messagerie extends Activity {
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.messagerie);

    new UpdateLocation().execute();

}

public void majCoordonnes() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Fournisseur :");
    stringBuilder.append("\n");
    stringBuilder.append(locationProvider);
    stringBuilder.append(" : ");
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

    if (location != null) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String lon = String.valueOf(longitude);

        stringBuilder.append(latitude);
        stringBuilder.append(", ");
        stringBuilder.append(longitude);


                    //Send location to server in an AsyncTask
        new sendLocation().execute(lat, lon);


    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("Non déterminée");
    }
    Log.d("MaPositionMaj", stringBuilder.toString());
}


/**
 * Ecouteur utilisé pour les mises à jour des coordonnées
 */
class MajListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        majCoordonnes();
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
};




//Requête GET, mise à jour des infos
private class UpdateLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String resp;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
        //Recuperation Location
        String locationContext = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(locationContext);
        if (locationManager != null && locationProvider != null) {

            majCoordonnes();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 120000, 500, new MajListener());


        }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Exception1", e.getMessage());
        }

        return resp;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

EDIT: I think I have to use a Service instead of an asyncTask.

Comment: @user40574: hi, explain your problem in a more clear manner, Do you got any expectation in your Logcat or the foreround thread failed to update data?????????????????????/

Comment: I've just updated my post with logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: I think I have to use a Service instead of an asyncTask.

Precisely. Creating a separate thread will not ensure that it is not killed when the application / activity exits, or when the operating system needs more resources. A `Service` doesn't ensure that either -- it may still be killed if the system is under really heavy load, but it's much less likely. Also (correct me if I'm wrong), Android will restart the Service once the system load softens.

Comment: What about using a Timer(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead of a service?

Comment: @Flo I don't see how a `Timer` would help. It won't stop Android killing your process.

Comment: Mh, I thought a Timer can be seen as a cron job object which let me trigger some functionality periodically and that it could call this functionality although the application isn't running. I had something in my mind like a broadcast receiver that can start an activity although the the application of this activity is not running. So the Timer is directly bound to the application? Then of course you're right, this won't solve this problem.

Comment: @Flo yes, the `Timer` is bound to the current process. You can start an `Activity` from a `BroadcastReceiver`, but someone needs to call your `BroadcastReceiver` first. For what you're trying to do, I think the `AlarmManager` is best suited. You can check out the following blog post that I wrote about something very similar, which I think will help you: http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html

Comment: Oh ok, then I mixed up AlarmManager with Timer. Sorry for that. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just call (write it down in your code) `Looper.prepare()`, before you run your `Thread`. (It's a simple solution, but previously made me weird too.)

If you can't call the `Handler` which is in your `Activity`, then firstly, you should make your activity constructor, for example :

```
public SampleActivity() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

then in your `ASyncTask`, initiate that `Activity`:

```
SampleActivity sampleAct = new SampleActivity();
```

and the final kick is call your `Handler`.

```
sampleAct.handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

I hope this clearly explains it to you.