# Timer is not wroking when asynctask() is called inside the timer

Tags: android, exception, timer, initializer

I have created a service in which I am running a timer for checking latest change in data to show notification for the change.
This same code has run perfectly on my previous apps.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    TimerTask task1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("timertag", "inside run of timer");
            getnotification(); // mothed defined in class
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();  
    timer.schedule(task1,1000,60*1000); 
}
```

Exception that comes on execution:

```
05-20 12:29:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13894): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
05-20 12:29:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13894): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: Using Handler class  or Runnable Interface for call after a delay. I think this one is pretty easy

Comment: TimerTask implements Runnable. So that there is a problem to initialize a thread within the other thread. The same thing will be happen if you use Handler.postDelayed();
Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860404/cant-call-handler-in-an-asynctask and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857343/asynctask-cannot-work-in-thread-android